# Estimate of Fourier Coefficient

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Knowing $f \in C^r(\mathbb{R})$
$$c_n(\hat{f}) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x)e^{-inx}dx, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$ 
I am trying to show that  $$\mid c_n \mid \leqslant C_r (1 + {\mid n \mid}^{-r}) $$
I have been struggling the whole evening and I still can't see how the estimate depends on the smoothness $r$ and $n$. Since I just replaced $e^{-inx}$ by $1$ and I really don't know any other ways to deal with complex numbers. Thank you very much for your hint.

*Edit, I just found out that I am asked to show that $$\mid c_n \mid \leqslant C_r (1 + {\mid n \mid})^{-r} $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: In general $c_n = o(|n|^{-r})$ for $2\pi$-periodic $f \in C^r(\mathbb{R})$ and getting the exact form for your bound requires a little manipulation.

For $f \in C^1$ and $n \neq 0$, integration by parts yields

$$\begin{align}|c_n| &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left|i\frac{f(2\pi)e^{-i2\pi n} - f(0)}{n} - \frac{i}{n}\int_0^{2\pi} f'(x)e^{-inx} \, dx\right| \\ &\leqslant  \frac{|f(2\pi) - f(0)|}{2\pi}+ \frac{1}{2\pi|n|}\int_0^{2\pi} |f'(x)| \, dx \\ &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left|\int_0^{2\pi}f'(x) \, dx \right|+ \frac{1}{2\pi|n|}\int_0^{2\pi} |f'(x)| \, dx \\ & \leqslant \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f'(x)| \, dx \left(1 + |n|^{-1} \right)  \end{align}$$

For $f \in C^r$ use repeated integration by parts.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you also explain the case when $n = 0$? I struggled to find the estimate since integration by part will not work.

Comment: @AlvisNordkovich: You're welcome.  The constant I gave you for the $C^1$ case is $C = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f'(x)| \, dx$ and since $f'$ is bounded we can get a larger bound $C \leqslant \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\|f'\|_{\infty} \, dx = \|f'\|_{\infty}$.  Why worry about the case $n=0$ since the expression $(1 +|n|^{-1})$ is not even defined?  Also $c_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \, dx$ is just a number.

Comment: Maybe try to bound $c_0$ in terms of $\|f'\|_{\infty}$ using $\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \, dx = \int_0^{2\pi} \left( f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t) \, dt \right) \, dx$ to try to get some common constant.  However, at this point I don't see the context of these extensions to the original question.  If it gets too much more complicated you should ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming  that your function $f$ has period $2\pi$. If $g=f^{(r)}$ then $c_n (\hat {g}) =(in)^{r} c_n(\hat {f})$. [This is proved by repeated integration by parts].  From this the inequality follow easily.